# how to get current GDG version through jcl

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

I have a code below to write the properties of the gdg to a PS file.

```
//STEP10  EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                              
//DD1       DD DSN='GDGBASE(0)',DISP=SHR  
//SYSPRINT  DD DSN=GDG.VERSION.PS,           
//             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                
//             UNIT=WORK,AVGREC=K,                     
//             SPACE=(108,(5,5),RLSE),                 
//             DCB=(BUFNO=10,RECFM=FB,LRECL=108)       
//SYSIN     DD *                                       
 PRINT INFILE(DD1) COUNT(0) CHAR                       
/*
```

But I just need the GDG's latest version name to be written in to the PS file.

Comment: You mean Generation, not Version. Consult your JCL Reference to find out the difference. You may go through your whole career without having to use a Version. You could use LISTCAT and get the dataset-name from the output of that. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using pure JCL. As a suggestion to get you started here's a short REXX and some JCL - it's not perfect, but you can tune it to fit your specific needs.

Part 1: a short REXX-script to display the DSN of an allocated file:

```
/* REXX find DSN for DD */ 
arg mydd                     
x= LISTDSI(mydd file)        
say sysdsname
```

Part 2: JCL to invoke it using batch-TSO:

```
//FINDDSN EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,PARM='DSNFIND MYFILE'    
//MYFILE   DD  DSN=MY.GDG.FILE(+0),DISP=SHR    
//SYSEXEC  DD  DSN=PDS.CONTAINING.REXX,DISP=SHR          
//SYSTSPRT DD  SYSOUT=*                                
//SYSTSIN  DD  DUMMY
```

where `DSNFIND` is the membername of the given REXX-procedure.

Output in SYSTSPRT is:

```
MY.GDG.FILE.G0338V00
READY                       
END
```

I haven't found a quick way to suppress the `READY` and `END` - but instead of `SAY` you could e.g. use `EXECIO` to write to an other file - `READY` and `END` would still go to `SYSTSPRT`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply, But I am getting the following error.                                                                     

PHASE 1 PROCESSING OF CLIST OR REXX EXEC ENDED ABNORMALLY +
ABEND CODE: S913    REASON CODE: 0038

Comment: Check your joblog - it might be a problem of insufficient access-privileges for some dataset.

Comment: Check your job log for ICH408I messages indicating to what resource RACF is blocking access.